# C programming, use of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am unable to understand the following code in С, using pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bags[5]={20,5,20,3,20};
int *next();

int main()
{
    int pos=5;
    *next()=pos;
    printf("%d,%d,%d",pos,*next(),bags[0]);
}

int *next()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(bags[i]==20)
        return(bags+i);
    printf("Error!");
}
```

Can anyone explain why the ans is `20,5,20`.

Comment: Well, I ran this code and I got the ans as `5,20,5`

Comment: This code invokes undefined behaviour if the `if` condition fails in `next` function.

Comment: @ajay In theory. In practice it *always* returns bags+i since i = 0 on he first iteration. So the loop is useless, i=0 would do.

Comment: @jens First iteration yes.. future iterations no, as the values may have changed

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't see any future iterations in the program as is. next() is called only once and bags never modified.

Comment: aday's point was that the expression `*next()` is unsafe in general, even though this particular program doesn't trigger UB, so it is bad design

Answer (score 3):

The output of the program will is,

```
5,20,5
```

because

```
if(bags[i]==20)
        return(bags+i);
```

returns pointer to `bags[0]` since `bags[0]==20` and return is a pointer to it and

```
*next()=pos;
```

writes `pos` value to the address pointed by `next()` returned address, i.e. `bags[0]=pos=5`

Comment: ya sorry the output will be 5,20,5.I was experimenting with the input data so mistakenly copied the wrong data. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

The function `next` returns a pointer to the first array element equal to 20.
So, `*next()=pos;` will modify the first element of the array from 20 to 5.
Then it is simple to understand why the output is `5,20,5`: since `pos` is five, `*next()` returns 20 and `bags[0]` is 5 as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

The output is `5,20,5`.

Note: `int *next();` ==> `next()` is a function that returns `int*`.

[1] The call to `next()` from the line `*next() = pos;`. C evaluates the function from left so `next()` gets called first. Because of `if (bags[i] == 20)`, the function `next()` returns `bags+i` which is simply `bags` since `i` is `0` at the moment. So `next()` returned the address of `bags` which means `*next()` is nothing but the pointer to `bags[0]`. So `bags[0]` becomes `5`.

[2] When the execution comes to this line: `printf("%d,%d,%d",pos,*next(),bags[0]);`, it prints value of `pos` i.e `5`, value of `*next()` which is `20` as `next()` returned the address of `bags[0]`.

[3] `*next()` prints `20` because, this time next will return the address of `bags[2]` since `bags[0]` got assigned with the value of `pos` in the line before the `printf()`.

[4] And finally, `bags[0]` is `5`. See the explanation in [1].